# Cannot infer correct lifetime when borrowing index of slice and field of a struct at once

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a double buffer in Rust, so when I get the current buffer, it does `self.buffers[self.index]`.
For the sake of brevity, I made that into a function so I could call it like this:

```rust
pub struct Screen<'a> {
    pub canvas: Canvas<'a>,
    pub buffers: [Vec<u32>; 2],
    pub index: usize,
}

impl<'a> Screen<'a> {
    #[inline(always)]
    pub fn get_buf<'b>(&'a self) -> &[u32] {
        self.buffers[self.index].as_slice()
    }
    #[inline(always)]
    pub fn get_mut_buf<'b>(&mut self) -> &mut [u32] {
        self.buffers[self.index].as_mut_slice()
    }
    pub fn clear(&mut self, color: u32) {
        for pixel in self.get_mut_buf().iter_mut() {
            *pixel = color;
        }
    }
    pub fn swap_buffers(&mut self) {
        self.canvas.data.copy_from_slice(&self.buffers[self.index]);
        self.index += 1;
        if self.index >= self.buffers.len() {
            self.index = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this is invalid:

```
pub fn swap_buffers(&mut self) {
    self.canvas.data.copy_from_slice(self.get_buf());
    self.index += 1;
    if self.index >= self.buffers.len() {
        self.index = 0;
    }
}
```

While this isn't:

```
pub fn swap_buffers(&mut self) {
    self.canvas.data.copy_from_slice(&self.buffers[self.index]);
    self.index += 1;
    if self.index >= self.buffers.len() {
        self.index = 0;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

I even tried encapsulating the real buffer inside a struct (in this case, Canvas) since I saw somewhere that could help because borrowing fields instead of the whole struct solves problems like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust you can't take a mutable reference and an immutable reference of the same thing at the same time. This is described nicely in the book [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html).

Basically in the second case the compiler is able to see that `.canvas` and `.buffers` are different things.

In the first case `get_buf` returns a `&[u32]` reference that has the same lifetime as `&self` meaning that when `self.get_buf()` is called it takes an immutable reference to the the entire `Screen` struct. The compiler won't let you take a mutable reference to `.canvas` because it is part of `self` and you are already using an immutable reference to `self`.