# Lifetime parameter in function call has conflicting requirements

Tags: rust

I have a `Screen` struct which holds two mutable slices for buffers and one for a canvas:

```rust
pub struct Screen<'a> {
    pub canvas: Canvas<'a>,
    pub buffers: [Vec<u32>; 2],
    pub index: usize,
}
```

Methods to borrow the buffers and a method do swap and write them:

```rust
impl<'a> Screen<'a> {
    pub fn get_buf(&'a self) -> &[u32] {
        self.buffers[self.index].as_slice()
    }
    pub fn get_mut_buf(&mut self) -> &mut [u32] {
        self.buffers[self.index].as_mut_slice()
    }
    pub fn swap_buffers(&mut self) {
        self.canvas.copy_from_slice(self.get_buf());
        self.bufnum += 1;
        if self.bufnum == self.buffers.len() {
            self.bufnum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that, as answered in another thread ([Cannot infer correct lifetime when borrowing index of slice and field of a struct at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946390/cannot-infer-correct-lifetime-when-borrowing-index-of-slice-and-field-of-a-struc)), the compiler can't see `self.buffers` and `self.canvas` as different things, so I tried to assign a new `'b` lifetime to `buffers`, but it resulted in it having conflicting requirements somehow:

```rust
struct Screen<'a, 'b> {
    pub canvas: &'a mut [u32],
    pub buffers: [&'b mut [u32]; 2],
    pub bufnum: usize,
}

impl<'a, 'b> Screen<'a, 'b> {
    pub fn get_buf(&self) -> &'b [u32] {
        self.buffers[self.bufnum]
    }
    pub fn get_mut_buf(&mut self) -> &'b mut [u32] {
        &mut self.buffers[self.bufnum]
    }
    pub fn swap_buffers(&mut self) {
        self.canvas.copy_from_slice(self.get_buf());
        self.bufnum += 1;
        if self.bufnum == self.buffers.len() {
            self.bufnum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem and still be able to use `get_but` and `get_mut_buf`?

Comment: You can solve the initial error by marking `&mut self` on the other methods as `&'a mut self`. However, I think you will find you will get the same issue as you had in your previous post.

Some advice: in Rust if you find yourself "fighting the borrow checker" you might want to rethink your design. In my experience I find it easier to have a consuming functions  `self` that return a new `Screen` than `&mut self` functions. They are often easier to understand as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried doing `'a mut self` but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use your original struct.

```
match self {
    Screen { index, buffers, index } => {
        // the parts are separate &mut references here
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually does not answer my question in first place. I *know* this is the clear answer, but I want to improve my knowledge about the borrow checker and solve this problem.